# Android with black borders in Miracast Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, android, miracast

I have a similar problem described here: [Microsoft Wireless Display: black border around image (screen image is scaled down)](https://superuser.com/questions/1352562/microsoft-wireless-display-black-border-around-image-screen-image-is-scaled-do)

However, I'm casting from an Android phone (the native casting called Smart View) to a Windows 10 PC. In fulscreen on the PC I can read the phone, but when I resize it the borders show up and make impossible to see. Android cast has an option named fullscreen on connected device, but activating it does not solve the issue. See the screenshot. Any help?

[image]

Comment: What is the display resolution of the casting Android device and what is the original size of the image you have posted?

Comment: It's a Galaxy A8, screen resolution 1080x2220. The screenshot is 500x810px. My PC fullscreen is 1920x1080px.